# Increasing resolution of CentOS VM

Tags: centos, vmware, resolution

I have a CentOS v7.2 virtual machine.

How do I tell what the available resolutions are that I can change too?

Then, how do I go about changing between the available resolutions to one that is easier on the eyes?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm running a minimal CentOS installation, meaning I only have the terminal to work with, no GUI.

Comment: My desire is to use the entire "or majority" width and height of my monitor.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this post.  I'm using VMware workstation to run this VM.  My solutions:

1. I shutdown the guest
2. I enabled VNC connections to my VM
3. I downloaded the VNC Viewer
4. I connect to the guest with value localhost:0
5. Upper-left corner of VNC Viewer, right-click, Properties option, Options tab, scale to fit window option

Other change that helped was modifying font size:

1. Fonts are at /lib/kbd/consolefonts
2. In terminal run: setfont some-filename-in-consolefonts